# Is it possible to complete Death Wind 1 in first place, using the Blue Falcon on Master class?

Tags: f-zero

Recently I've been playing SNES F-Zero on my free time.

After many pain and practice, now I can win the first place on Master class with Capt. Falcon on all the tracks, except for Death Wind 1.
With some luck, the most I've been able to get there is the second place, but that's it.

It'd be great to see someone doing on a real console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search returned this:

[image: Yes]

Notice the lack of the Blue Falcon. According to [looklapauza](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txThD6tvmtQ):

> The only way to win the first place with Blue Falcon (no idea the others), in this track on Master class, SEEMS TO BE the CPU players to hit the laggers.

To be honest, I'm not familliar enough with the older games to tell you, but there's my research.